# mosquitto installation lsb-base error

Tags: ubuntu, debian, mosquitto

I was installing mosquitto and got an error

```
mosquitto : Depends: lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian3) but 4.0-0ubuntu20.2 is to be installed
```

I looked for it but couldn't find any solution.
Can anybody please help ?

Comment: your question should be asked on [su] (please ask for migration)

Answer (score 0):

you have a version mismatch.

if possible you should install `mosquitto` for the release of Ubuntu you are running (not for some other Debian release).

If that is not possible, you might have more luck installing `mosquitto` for an older version of Debian (that did not ship with `lsb_base>=4.1` yet).

If that's not possible, try to install `mosquitto` from source (rather than using the debian packages)

If that's not possible, install a recent Debian on your system.

Answer (score 0):

This was down to a problem with the mosquitto ubuntu packaging that is now fixed.